# Co-pay vs copartnership: Prefix hyphenation in AmE

Tags: american-english, orthography, hyphenation, prefixes, north-american-english

In AmE, we tend to close up prefixes like co-, re-, pre-, post-, etc. unless the first letter of the main word is the same vowel as the last letter of the prefix. But I see some exceptions like *preemtive* that defy the rule (I should convince myself that the vowel *e* is an exception). While I understand why we use a hyphen for *re-sign* to differentiate it from *resign*, I don’t understand the logic behind **[co-pay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/co-pay)**. Is there any material of authority that helps a non-native speaker like me to understand which are the words that should be closed up (say, whether co-utilize should be closed up)?

Answer (score 2):

The decision to hyphenate or not hyphenate is purely stylistic, thus the authority on the matter would be whatever style guide your publisher/editor/teacher uses.

There are numerous style guides, none of which is more correct than any other.

One commonly used style, called *APA Style* offers these guidelines:

> **General Principle 1**
>
> If a compound adjective can be misread, use a hyphen.
>
> **General Principle 2**
>
> In a temporary compound that is used as an adjective before a noun, use a hyphen if the term can be misread or if the term expresses a single thought (i.e., all words together modify the noun)...
>
> Also use hyphens for
>
> Compounds in which the base word is
>
> - capitalized: pro-Freudian
> - a number: post-1970
> - an abbreviation: pre-UCS trial
> - more than one word: non-achievement-oriented students
>
> All "self-" compounds whether they are adjectives or nouns
>
> - self-report
> - self-esteem
>
> https://www.apastyle.org/learn/faqs/when-use-hyphen